# Enable others to mail web pages to my kindle/pocket

Tags: email, kindle

There is facility in both kindle and pocket which allows us to send Web page links to these services which in turn convert it to text view enabling us to read it later. However, is there a way someone else can send me Web pages which go directly to our kindle /pocket. 
Let's say a friend of mine comes across a good article on a certain Web page and wants to share it with me. Is there a way possible for him to directly send the  link to my kindle device/pocket such that I get the article directly without visiting that web page?

The send to kindle address @kindle.com only allows others to send documents and not links to web pages. Similarly add@getpocket.com only allows one to send links from an email id which is not registered to any other pocket user. My friend also has pocket and when I try to add my friend's email address it says that the email is associated with another pocket account. Basically pocket does not have a universal identifier for users essentially allowing only the user to mail links to himself/herself. 
Is there any workaround possible for this scenario? Can anyone suggest an ifttt or another DIY solution?

Comment: Your friend could generate an ebook using the [grabmybooks](http://www.grabmybooks.com/) extension for firefox and then send it to you. If you want to use getpocket, maybe you should write them a mail containing your idea for the new feature.

Comment: Mind you, opening the possibility of "Others" to send web pages to your Pocket may means spammer would send their web pages to your kindle. Hopefully if they did implement the idea, they have a 'whitelist' that the owner of the account have to explicitly set who can send them web pages...

Comment: @Tim yeah that is the whole point - No one is going to convert a webpage first to send it to someone else specially when a lot of pages have to be shared everyday. they would simply send it to me email which can be done in 1 or two clicks. That is the whole problem - I want an automated solution which is almost invisible to others and yet keeps my inbox free of emails containing links to articles. They should be able to send it to a certain email address like send-to-kindle address which should handle it automatically.

Comment: @Tim I have already sent it to pocket guys but it will probably be months before they come out with any feature if at all.

Comment: @Suy I just noticed, that the new version of grabmybooks allows to send the generated book to a mail address. You can however only specify one. You could test, if it works for you and then send them a feature request to allow sending to one of multiple addresses from a conveniently reachable button.

Comment: Otherwise I suppose you could write a script that does what you want using calibre. But I do not know enough about it to give you any advice for this.

Comment: No no it's not exactly what I want to do. I want others to be able to simply mail a link to a certain email address and some software/service to grab that link and send it to my device automatically. The other person should simply have something like my mailing address and simply send the link there. I was hoping something could be done using some Gmail filter to automatically forward all mails from a certain account of mine to pocket Web service so that it automatically appears in my pocket app.

Comment: @Suy A Gmail filter or mailing list sounds if it could work. Just try it and report back if it works. If you answer to someone's comment on StackExchange and want him to be notified, start your comment with @ and the username. He will then be notified.

Comment: @Tim I've tried it actually. The only problem is that before adding a forwarding address it requires a confirmation code which it sends to the forwarding address. However, Pocket or Kindle are not mail services and will reject all mails if they do not contain a link or a document respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. There is another service known as [Readability](http://www.readability.com) which offers a unique email id to which people can mail any link and it automatically converts it to an article view. It also has apps for most platforms which will download an article.
Visit the website for further details.